# loopback modify access token

Tags: access-token, loopbackjs

I want to add more details to the access token which is generated on calling the user login method. I have extended the builtin user model with my own Customer model. My login method looks like below:

```
getToken(userData, data, callback) {
        const Customer = app.models.Customer;
        Customer.login(
            { email: userData.email, password: userData.password },
            function (error, accessToken) {
                if (error) {
                    callback(error);
                } else {
                    callback(null, accessToken);
                }
            }
        )   
    }
```

I want to add data to the accessToken on login. How do I achieve that ? Basically I want to add more information to accessToken other than userId. I also want to retain userId in the token.

Thanks

Comment: You should add them as claims into your access token. your question is ambigious. which access token provider do you use?

Comment: @MortezaZabihi, quickly realized that I can do it other way round. Hence, modified the question.